# Magento - Dropdown box

Tags: magento, country

Does anyone know how to get a dropdown box like this [one](http://www.paulsmith.co.uk/uk-en/shop/information/delivery-information.html)? I'm trying to get a list of countries with separate delivery prices. P.S. trying to put this on a CMS page.

Answer (score 1):

you can create drop down in front end like below

```
<?php $_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
                                    ->loadData()
                                    ->toOptionArray(false) ?>
<?php if (count($_countries) > 0): ?>
    <select name="country" id="country">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <?php foreach($_countries as $_country): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_country['value'] ?>">
                <?php echo $_country['label'] ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And for **Admin view**

```
<?php

    $fieldset->addField('country', 'select', array(
        'name'  => 'country',
        'label'     => 'Country',
        'values'    => Mage::getModel('adminhtml/system_config_source_country')->toOptionArray(), 
    ));

?>
```

hope this will sure help you